# How to apply affine transform to component's childs?

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

Is it possible to apply transformations to custom or premade controls in Swing? By one hand transformations are allowed, by other hand there are probably some gaps in implementation with this.

**ATTENTION** the question is about how to apply transfomations from control's parent, not about how to use transformations at all. I.e. transformation must be issued by the parent, while child should just obey it. So, please hint how to transform standard Swing controls or how to write custom controls which obey PARENT transformation.

Simple example which applies transform to `Graphics` before drawing childs and which doesn't work:

```
public class Tester_TransformDuringPaint_01 {

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tester_TransformDuringPaint_01.class);  
private static class JPanelEx extends JPanel {
private AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();

    public AffineTransform getTransform() {
        return transform;
    }

    public void setTransform(AffineTransform transform) {
        this.transform = transform;
    }       

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform savedTransform = g2.getTransform();
        g2.transform(transform);
        super.paintComponent(g);            
        g2.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);            
        g2.setTransform(savedTransform);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform savedTransform = g2.getTransform();
        g2.transform(transform);
        super.paintChildren(g);
        g2.setTransform(savedTransform);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            button.setBounds(0,20,100,60);              
            JPanelEx panel = new JPanelEx();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            panel.setBounds(10, 10, 640, 480);
            panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            panel.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2, 1));
            panel.add(button);
            JFrameEx frame = new JFrameEx();
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.add(panel);               
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);               
            frame.setSize(0.5);
            frame.center();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

draws the following:

[image]

while left half of the button looks alive, and bigger part looks dead.

This is because different pars of API draws button with different approach.

**Modified O'Reilly hack 51**

Below is the code based on @lbalazscs's example, which shows that transformations don't work even if they are "in bounds"

```
public class BackwardsJButton extends JButton {

public BackwardsJButton(String text) {
    super(text);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform savedTransform = g2.getTransform();
        AffineTransform flipTrans = new AffineTransform();
        double widthD = (double) getWidth();
        //flipTrans.setToTranslation(widthD, 0);
        //flipTrans.scale(-2.0, 1);
        flipTrans.scale(0.5, 1);
        g2.transform(flipTrans);
        super.paint(g);
        g2.setTransform(savedTransform);
    } else {
        super.paint(g);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            buildFrame();
        }
    });
}

private static void buildFrame() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f.add(new BackwardsJButton("BackwardsJLabel"));

    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

output follows (you may need to resize window and move mouse to see it, because Swing bug is located inside mouse hover code:

[image]

Comment: If you want to transform components in this way, you should check out JXLayer

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve exactly what I wrote.

Comment: you must have a higher reason for turning loose all demons in hell ;-) Particularly: _apply transfomations from control's parent_ smells like doctoring on symptons of a perceived solution (instead of stating the base goal and go from there) - it's fighting the winds of Swing instead of floating on them.

Comment: I want to have something like custom graphics editor, but not exactly. I need some reusable component (like extended `JPanel`) on which I could put my own geometric figures, like plots or shapes. I was thinking all this can be implemented by extending panels and components, but winds of Swing resist. Actually they always tend me to create my own single component which does everything by hand, i.e. Swing winds try to blow me out of Swing totally. Unfortunately I can't ask for Swing alternative here because I can imagine vulcanoes of hate will happen :D

Comment: Actually it should be not an editor, because I need not interacting with the user much, but I need to present some shapes and change them dynamically from my program.

Answer (score 4):

You have some innovative ideas how to abuse Swing :)

It is possible to apply affine transform while drawing components, but only if you are happy within the bounds of the component(for example you could mirror the text). If you override paint, you change how the component is drawn, but this will not change its size because the size depends on completely other variables, and you still cannot draw reliably outside its bounds.

I think it is not a good idea to transform the painting of premade components, because even if you succeed graphically, mouse clicks will be expected in the original places.

Note that you need to reset the transformation after you are done, because the same Graphics object will be used to paint other components.

```
AffineTransform savedTransform = g.getTransform();
g.setTransform(specialTransform);
... your drawing here
g.setTransform(savedTransform);
```

EDIT: here is a complete running example of a transformed component

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class ScaledButton extends JButton {

    public ScaledButton(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color savedColor = g2.getColor();
        g2.setColor(getBackground());
        g2.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
        g2.setColor(savedColor);

        AffineTransform backup = g2.getTransform();
        g2.scale(0.5, 1);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2.setTransform(backup);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform backup = g2.getTransform();
        g2.scale(0.5, 1);
        super.paintBorder(g);
        g2.setTransform(backup);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                buildFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void buildFrame() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.add(new ScaledButton("ScaledButton"));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I should return transformation to original state. But what if want to use transformation?

Comment: I have wrote as you suggest to make code more "polite". But the question persist.

Comment: Now with `g2.setTransform(savedTransform);` I see only one (small) button, which is logical because the button painting has no transformation. Previously it was only an accident, that the button got scaled (it used the same Graphics object). Note that you didn't include the source of JFrameEx, so I used a simple JFrame.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a running example of a transformed component.

Comment: Ah sorry my last edit really removed an effect because children drawing occur in other method. See my new update, it works with partial transforming as previously, because no I introduce transformation is `paintChildren` method.

Comment: P.S. `JFrameEx` is mostly like `JFrame` but with few helper methods like `center()`.

Comment: I modified your example slightly: (1) changed header to `public class BackwardsJButton extends JButton`, (2) changed scale line to `flipTrans.scale(-2.0, 1)`, (3) layout set to `FlowLayout` `f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`. And you will see similar effect. O"Reilly just occasionally found a control (`JLabel`) which works ok with flipping. `JButton` doesn't work well with scaling.

Comment: Well, if you override paint, you change how the component is drawn, but this will not change its size because the size depends on completely other variables, and you still cannot draw reliably outside its bounds. BTW, you need no center() method, `f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` also centers a frame like in my example.

Comment: so is it possible to apply affine transform while drawing components? there is only a flipping in your demo; thanks for `hint()` about center; my `Ex` version also contains `close()` method which is apparently absent in default implementation

Comment: it is possible, but only if you are happy within the bounds (like a mirroring in my example), I think that no technique will help you to draw reliably outside the bounds

Comment: in my example I am within the bounds. Bounds are `panel.setBounds(10, 10, 640, 480);`

Comment: Also you can replace `flipTrans.setToTranslation(widthD, 0);` and `flipTrans.scale(-1.0, 1);` (two lines) with `flipTrans.scale(0.5, 1);` (one line) in your example and you will see that it won't work with `JButton` despite the fact it will be "within the bounds" example.

Comment: OK, I changed my example to include a (0.5, 1) scaling, by overriding paintBorder as well, and clearing the background in paintComponent. Of course, the button responds to mouse clicks within its whole bound, as I warned you at the very beginning. I think it is time to accept this answer, and ask other questions in separate questions :)

Comment: Ok, it works. But can you extend `JPanel` in the same way so that buttons can be added to it as childs and transformed?

Comment: Oops, you should have asked that earlier, I am not going to write now another example program for you... Consider overriding *only* paintChildren, and don't forget to clear the background. In worst case you can take an image with the normal Graphics, and paint that.

Comment: This was initial question read carefully pls. I can't grant you an answer then, only upvote, sorry...